# How to run the http request ( based on the regular expression output from previous http request )by adding if controller

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a regular expression ${Fax} in the http request1 which returns a value Ex: b4mL0000000NDKF and I would like to add a if controller in the next http request2 so it can only run if the reg exp from previous http request1 i.e., ${Fax} returns a value otherwise (if the regexp from http request1 returns 'Match count: 0'), I don't want to run the http request2 (because I am using the value of reg exp ${Fax} in the next http request --> Path)

Could you tell me the condition that I can write in the If Controller which controls the http request2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) you have [__isVarDefined()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__isVarDefined) function which returns `true` or `false` depending whether the given variable is defined or not.

So you can use `${__isVarDefined(Fax)}` expression as the [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) condition

[image: JMeter If Controller isVarDefined]

Comment: Thanks, I am able to skip the http request using the expression ${__isVarDefined(Fax)} in JMeter 4.0